# How to use goto-like functionality in Processing?

Tags: processing, khan-academy

I am learning to code in Khan academy. It uses processing as its base language. I learnt that Java doesn't have goto function with it. Then how to implement goto function using processing. Explanatio with snippet is appreciated.

Here's my code and I have comment the places where I want to use the goto functionality:

```js
/* Returns either the index of the location in the array,
  or -1 if the array did not contain the targetValue */

var doSearch = function(array, targetValue) {
    var min = 0;
    var max = array.length - 1;
    var guess;

    //startover:

    if (guess === max || guess === min) {
      //goto notFound;
    }

    guess = round((min + max) / 2);

    if (targetValue === array[guess]) {
      return guess;
    } else {
      if (targetValue > array[guess]) {
        min = guess + 1;
        //goto startover;
      } else {
        max = guess - 1;
        //goto startover;
      }
    }
  }
  //notFound:
return -1;
};

var primes = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37,
  41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97
];

var result = doSearch(primes, 73);
println("Found prime at index " + result);

//Program.assertEqual(doSearch(primes, 73), 20);
```

Comment: Do not use goto. it kills the execution flow, highly inefficient, not readable http://www.drdobbs.com/jvm/programming-with-reason-why-is-goto-bad/228200966

Comment: Better to ask about a specific problem or idea you have, rather than ask about a language feature that does not exist. Processing is based on Java, and both do not have goto, as they are structured languages. Maybe work through some of the Processing tutorials? https://www.processing.org/tutorials/

Comment: I have been coding in C++ for well over a decade.  The only time I have seen `goto` used in a way that actually *needed* to be `goto` was in parser code autogenerated by YACC or BISON.  Developers almost universally agree that `goto` is not worth the problems it cause, and it should almost always be avoided.

Comment: Why not just use the array prototype "indexOf" https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

Answer (score 0):

The best you could probably do is to use a for loop and use `break` or `continue` for `goto`s.

```
for(var unusedVariable = 0;1==1;unusedVariable++){//equivalent of "startover:"
    if(condition1){
        continue;//goto startover;
    }
    if(condition2){
        continue;//goto startover;
    }
    if(condition1){
        break;//goto notFound;
    }
}//notFound:
```